# O's and X's won't show in Javascript Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a simple JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe game through following along a beginner guide to making one. I followed it to the letter but I'm running into a problem where once I try to see it on the HTML page, the crosses for the game show-up but when I try to click to put my X's and O's, they don't appear. I'm not sure what could be the problem, can anyone help?

I've gone over my code to be sure I followed along with the guide correctly. In my HTML, I put my java Script tags at the bottom to make sure they load properly, but that didn't help much.

```js
const PLAYER_X_CLASS = "x";

const PLAYER_O_CLASS = "circle";

const WINNING_COMBITNATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [(3, 4, 5)],
  [(6, 7, 8)],
  [(0, 3, 6)],
  [(1, 4, 7)],
  [(2, 5, 8)],
  [(0, 4, 8)],
  [
    [2, 4, 6]
  ],
];

const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cell]");
const boardElement = document.getElementById("board");
const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById("winningMessage");
const restartButton = document.getElementById("restartButton");
const winningMessageTextElement = document.getElementById("winningMessageText");
let isPlayer_O_Turn = false;

startGame();

restartButton.addEventListener("click", startGame);

function startGame() {
  isPlayer_O_Turn = false;
  cellElements.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.classList.remove(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
    cell.classList.remove(PLAYER_O_CLASS);
    cell.removeEventListener("click", handleCellClick);
    cell.addEventListener("click", handleCellClick, {
      once: true
    });
  });
  setBoardHoverClass();
  winningMessageElement.classList.remove("show");
}

function handleCellClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target;
  const currentClass = isPlayer_O_Turn ? PLAYER_O_CLASS : PLAYER_X_CLASS;
  placeMark(cell, currentClass);
  if (checkWin(currentClass)) {
    endGame(false);
  } else if (isDraw()) {
    endGame(true);
  } else {
    swapTurns();
    setBoardHoverClass();
  }
}

function endGame(draw) {
  if (draw) {
    winningMessageTextElement.innerText = "It's a draw!";
  } else {
    winningMessageTextElement.innerText =
      'Player with ${isPlayer_O_Turn ? "O\'s" : "X\'s"} wins!';
  }

  winningMessageElement.classList.add("show");
}

function isDraw() {
  return [...cellElements].every((cell) => {
    return (
      cell.classList.contains(Player_X_CLASS) ||
      cell.classList.contains(PLAYER_O_CLASS)
    );
  });
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass);
}

function swapTurns() {
  isPlayer_O_Turn = !isPlayer_O_Turn;
}

function setBoardHoverClass() {
  boardElement.classList.remove(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
  boardElement.classList.remove(PLAYER_O_CLASS);

  if (IsPlayer_O_Turn) {
    boardElement.classList.add(PLAYER_O_CLASS);
  } else {
    boardElement.classList.add(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
  }
}

function checkWin(currentClass) {
  return WINNING_COMBITNATIONS.some((combination) => {
    return combination.every((index) => {
      return cellElements[index].classList.contains(currentClass);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --cell-size: 100px;
  --color: #81c3fd;
  --color-set: #0275d8;
  --1: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.board {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)
}

.cell {
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* remove border for edges */

.cell:nth-child(1),
.cell:nth-child(2),
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(1),
.cell:nth-child(4),
.cell:nth-child(7) {
  border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(3),
.cell:nth-child(6),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-right: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(7),
.cell:nth-child(8),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cell.x,
.cell.circle {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


/* for cross */

.board.x .cell:not(.circle):not(.x):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - var(--l) / 2), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--l) / 2) calc(50% + var(--l) / 2), transparent calc(50% + var(--l) / 2)), linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - var(--l) / 2), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--l) / 2) calc(50% + var(--l) / 2), transparent calc(50% + var(--l) / 2));
  background-size: 80% 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


/* for cross (set) */

.cell:not(.circle).x {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - var(--l) / 2), var(--color-set) calc(50% - var(--l) / 2) calc(50% + var(--l) / 2), transparent calc(50% + var(--l) / 2)), linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - var(--l) / 2), var(--color-set) calc(50% - var(--l) / 2) calc(50% + var(--l) / 2), transparent calc(50% + var(--l) / 2));
  background-size: 80% 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


/*for circle */

.board.circle .cell.not(.circle):not(.x):hover {
  background: radial-gradient(var(--color) 60%, transparent 60%);
}


/* for circle (set) */

.cell:not(.x).circle {
  background: radial-gradient(var(--color-set) 60%, transparent 60%)
}

.winning-message {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-set);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.winning-message button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-set);
  padding: .25em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.winning-message button:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-set);
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.winning-message.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Tic_Tac_Toe.css" />
<title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>

<div class="board" id="board">
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
</div>

<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
  <div id="winningMesssageText"></div>
  <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any CSS?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my post to show my CSS as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, include the HTML. You can even make it a runnable snippet using the `<>` button

Comment: I made the snippet, hope it helps.

Comment: Fix the typo please

Comment: Your `checkWin` function throws an error.  Each element of  `WINNING_COMBITNATIONS ` is an array, but you are using it as a number. Also, this syntax `[(3, 4, 5)]` evaluates to `[5]`, you wanted to use `[3, 4, 5]` instead.

Comment: I'm working on finding an answer to your question. I got the O's working just by fixing a couple syntax errors, but not sure on the X's; are you sure your CSS is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several syntax errors, which I was able to fix, but the main problem was that the CSS for the X's just didn't work at all. I fixed it by replacing the weird gradient magic you had that didn't work with a pseudo-element with the letter X in it.

```js
const PLAYER_X_CLASS = "x";

const PLAYER_O_CLASS = "circle";

const WINNING_COMBITNATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cell]");
const boardElement = document.getElementById("board");
const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById("winningMessage");
const restartButton = document.getElementById("restartButton");
const winningMessageTextElement = document.getElementById("winningMessageText");
let isPlayer_O_Turn = false;

startGame();

restartButton.addEventListener("click", startGame);

function startGame() {
  isPlayer_O_Turn = false;
  cellElements.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.classList.remove(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
    cell.classList.remove(PLAYER_O_CLASS);
    cell.removeEventListener("click", handleCellClick);
    cell.addEventListener("click", handleCellClick, {
      once: true,
    });
  });
  setBoardHoverClass();
  winningMessageElement.classList.remove("show");
}

function handleCellClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target;
  const currentClass = isPlayer_O_Turn ? PLAYER_O_CLASS : PLAYER_X_CLASS;
  placeMark(cell, currentClass);
  if (checkWin(currentClass)) {
    endGame(false);
  } else if (isDraw()) {
    endGame(true);
  } else {
    swapTurns();
    setBoardHoverClass();
  }
}

function endGame(draw) {

  if (draw) {
    winningMessageTextElement.textContent = "It's a draw!";
  } else {
    winningMessageTextElement.textContent = `Player with ${
      isPlayer_O_Turn ? "O's" : "X's"
    } wins!`;
  }

  winningMessageElement.classList.add("show");
}

function isDraw() {
  return [...cellElements].every((cell) => {
    return (
      cell.classList.contains(PLAYER_X_CLASS) ||
      cell.classList.contains(PLAYER_O_CLASS)
    );
  });
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass);
}

function swapTurns() {
  isPlayer_O_Turn = !isPlayer_O_Turn;
}

function setBoardHoverClass() {
  boardElement.classList.remove(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
  boardElement.classList.remove(PLAYER_O_CLASS);

  if (isPlayer_O_Turn) {
    boardElement.classList.add(PLAYER_O_CLASS);
  } else {
    boardElement.classList.add(PLAYER_X_CLASS);
  }
}

function checkWin(currentClass) {
  return WINNING_COMBITNATIONS.some((combination) => {
    return combination.every((index) => {
      return cellElements[index].classList.contains(currentClass);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --cell-size: 100px;
  --color: #81c3fd;
  --color-set: #0275d8;
  --1: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.board {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)
}

.cell {
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* remove border for edges */

.cell:nth-child(1),
.cell:nth-child(2),
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(1),
.cell:nth-child(4),
.cell:nth-child(7) {
  border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(3),
.cell:nth-child(6),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-right: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(7),
.cell:nth-child(8),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cell.x,
.cell.circle {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


/* for cross */

.board.x .cell:not(.circle, .x):hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: "\D7";
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: palevioletred;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* for cross (set) */

.cell.x::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: "\D7";
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*for circle */

.board.circle .cell:not(.circle, .x):hover {
  background: radial-gradient(var(--color) 60%, transparent 60%);
}


/* for circle (set) */

.cell:not(.x).circle {
  background: radial-gradient(var(--color-set) 60%, transparent 60%)
}

.winning-message {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-set);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.winning-message button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-set);
  padding: .25em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.winning-message button:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-set);
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.winning-message.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="board" id="board">
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
  <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
</div>

<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
  <div id="winningMessageText"></div>
  <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work to get the X's to show, but the O's don't show up. when I click all the squares, it's populated by all X's.